# WPF C# SelectedItem and SelectedValue with .tostring() method

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

this is a question just out of curiosity (it's working fine now), I'm writing a program using C# (WPF) and Access 2007, this is how the program works:

I have a ComboBox (let's call it CB1) with a list of items that gets populated from a table in Access, when a user selects an item from this ComboBox, another ComboBox (CB2) is filled with the items related to this selection (which is taken from another table), the thing is that when the user selects an item from CB1 and I compare the values like this:

```
foreach(DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
{
    if(row["item1"] == CB1.SelectedValue)
    {
        CB2.Items.Add(row["item2"]);
    }
}
```

It doesn't work properly due to the `.SelectedValue` property (doing it this way adds only 1 item to the CB2 list when sometimes it should add 2 items), however if I use `.SelectedValue.ToString()` to do the comparison it works fine (all items are added to CB2), so I guess my question would be... what's the difference in using `SelectedValue` vs `SelectedValue.ToString()` when comparing the values??, thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The two values you're comparing *both* return objects.

You'd expect at most a single match, because you're comparing object *references* (not the underlying  values). In other words, when you get a match using your code, it's because the object referenced by `row["item1"]` is the same object that's referenced by `CB1.SelectedValue`.

```
if (row["item1"] == CB1.SelectedValue)
```

Those objects could be strings, or numbers, or a more complex class that you've created.

---

If you know they're strings, cast them to strings:

```
if (Convert.ToString(row["item1"]) == Convert.ToString(CB1.SelectedValue))
```

If (for example) you knew they were integers, you should cast them to integers before comparing:

```
if (Convert.ToInt32(row["item1"]) == Convert.ToInt32(CB1.SelectedValue))
```

Answer (score 0):

CB1.SelectedValue represents a System.Object type. The .ToString() property converts the Object to type string, which presumably matches what you're selecting from your database. You were trying to compare an object to a string before, as opposed to comparing two strings.

The object class is described as:

> the ultimate base class of all classes in the .NET Framework; it is the root of the type hierarchy.

The behaviour is described as follows (according to MSDN):

> Setting SelectedValue to a value X attempts to select an item whose
>   value evaluates to X; if no such item can be found, the selection is
>   cleared.

More info on SelectedValue:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

More info on Object class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for your answer AugPopa!, however it is still not clear to me why it works fine the first time (when the first Item is added) but it ignores the other items =(